# Solving ModuleNotFoundError: Importing the module WoE and manipulating sys.path.append to allow my notebook to identify the new module

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sys.path

I just tried to install package WoE using pip which works fine. Then in Jupyter Notebook when I try to run the command:

from WoE import WoE

I receive an error that there is no module named "WoE"

I keep trying to figure out how to use sys.path.append to make this module work but I cannot figure it out. Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running command prompt as admin and then doing the command `py -m pip install WoE`. If that still doesn't work try restarting your computer, it could just be an issue with Jupyter not seeing the module yet. You can also do `py -m pip show WoE` and if that gives you a file location then that means it did install correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the help! when I do show WoE it gives me the file location which is different than where my project is saved. How can change the file path to start using this module?

Comment: It doesn't need to be in the same folder. You shouldn't need to change it, and this isn't something you should need to do again but try doing `import [path]` instead. That might fix it